# Select alternative libraries as a normal user

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, linker, libraries

I would like to have a normal user, with no `sudo` access, compile and run a program that uses `libblas` and `liblapack`, and do this with at least two versions of these libraries (ATLAS and OpenBLAS). With `update-alternatives` I can switch from one version to the other, but I need to use `sudo` for that.

Is there a way I could choose the libraries as a normal user? The compilation is using `-lblas -llapack` in the command line, maybe I can add the full path or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I could choose the libraries as a normal user?

Yes. Use `dpkg -x` on the two packages to extract them into separate directories, e.g.

```
mkdir ~/ATLAS; cd ~/ATLAS; dpkg -x /path/to/atlas-package.deb
mkdir ~/OpenBLAS; cd ~/OpenBLAS; dpkg -x /path/to/openblas-package.deb
```

Now you can link your programs to use one or the other:

```
gcc main.o -o use-atlas -lblas -llapack -L $HOME/ATLAS/lib -Wl,-rpath=$HOME/ATLAS/lib
gcc main.o -o use-openblas -lblas -llapack -L $HOME/OpenBLAS/lib -Wl,-rpath=$HOME/OpenBLAS/lib
```

(you may have to adjust the command above if the libraries are installed into something other than `/lib/`.

Comment: Thanks. Just creating links to the already installed library directories in `/usr/lib` and using these links in the `-L` and `-rpath` options seems to work.